# Testing R code under memory restrictions

Tags: r, linux, windows, testing, memory

I am running some R code on large files in the 1 to 4 GB range. Some of the code draws on packages that include compiled code written in other programming languages. I would like to know if this code will run on a machine with less RAM than I have, say 3 GB. Is there a way to restrict the memory available to R and RStudio for testing purposes? For my application, this must include the RAM available to any code that is called by R, even if it is written in another language. Either an R-level or an OS-level solution would be acceptable.

I am working on a Windows 7 machine.  I also plan on doing some testing on a Ubuntu virtual machine I have installed on this computer.

Comment: You can set memory limit function, but that will limit the total memory size of R as apposed to the maximum RAM ussage... There is a slight difference, since Windows (and maybe Ubuntu as well) uses virtual memory to store very large R workspaces (though much slower than its "physical" memory counterpart).

Comment: I am under the impression that this will limit the RAM available to R directly, but not to functions written in other languages but called by R. This is important for my application (unless it is wrong).

Comment: @Adam See question in my previous comment.

Comment: Some of the professors at my University helped write this, I can ask around if you still need an answer